# I cant print something after while-loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, cout

```
int main() 
{
    char word;
    int ascii_number , i =0 , sum = 0 ;
    
    while(word != '\n')
    {
        cin>>word;
        ascii_number = int(word);
        sum = sum + factorial(convert_decimal_to_binary(ascii_number));
        i = i+1;
        
    }
cout<<sum/i<<endl;
```

**in last line the "cout" doesn't work and the app hasn't any printout...
help please.**

Comment: This code has undefined behavior, because it accesses `word` before it has been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

```
 while(word != '\n')
```

This will never be true. Because, by default, std::cin has a setting to skip whitespace while reading char. To change that setting, use

```
std::cin >> std::noskipws;
```

This is to answer your specific question. There are other issues in your code, however, such as:

- on the first iteration, word is uninitialized.
- "word" is perhaps a bad choice for a variable name denoting a single char;
- the chosen way to increment i,
- the scope of some variables,
- etc.